# Supersized Jquery progress icon doens't go

Tags: jquery, supersized

I added the Supersized Jquery code within my page and everything works fine, except for the progress icon (gif) that won't show. I've tested in a lot of browsers. Please notice that Im talking about the progress icon (progress.gif) not about the progress bar.

**CSS:**

```
#supersized-loader {
position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; z-index:0; width:60px; height:60px;      margin:-30px 0 0 -30px; text-indent:-999em; background:url(img/progress.gif) no-repeat center center;}

#supersized {
position:fixed; left:0; top:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:-999; height:100%; width:100%; }

#supersized img{
width:auto; height:auto; position:relative; outline:none; border:none; }

#supersized a {
z-index:-30; position:fixed; overflow:hidden; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:#111; display:block; }

#supersized a.image-loading {
background:#111 url(img/progress.gif) no-repeat center center; width:100%; height:100%; }
```

**Jquery:**

```
jQuery(function($){

$.supersized({
slides  :  [ {image : 'img/backgroung001.png'} ]
});
});
```

Im wondering if I have to call it (progress.gif) within the Jquery code.
Help!
Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong.

You must use `$(".supersized")` to apply jQuery functions.